# How to give status of triggered send back as reply on api call to landing page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, api, ssjs, triggered-send

I have a cloud page that a customer accesses via an api call (do not know what kind).
The call holds an email address at a time. The landing page picks up the email address, does some other stuff and finally sends a triggered send to this address.

Now my customer needs a reply back giving the status of the triggered send.

I guess I can do like this

```
 <script runat=server>Platform.Load("core","1");

  var status = TriggeredSend.Init('Double_optin').Send(e,{
  SubscriberKey:e
  });
  Platform.Variable.SetValue("@status",status);

  </script>
  %%[
 if @status == "OK" then set @message_back = "Yes, worked out fine" endif
 ]%%
```

But how do I make that accessible as a reply back?

Answer (score 0):

When you say: reply back - do you mean an email message to your client with the status of the email send, or will a callback url be OK? You could for now implement [HTTPGet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httpget.htm) function in the email content, which fetches a unique URL and append parameters specific to the email and recipient. You will of course need to build a service able to receive this call.

With the upcoming (Jan 2019) release of SFMC, a new type of transactional sends will be provided, where you will be able to receive [notifications to a callback URL of your choice](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2019_platform_ens.htm&type=5).